# BitmapFactory.decodeFile returning null only in phone, not in emulator

Tags: android

I've got problem with this code. I want load image to imageview from path. When a use this code everything works fine

```
image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));
```

but when I use this one, on emulator is ok, but app stop working in phone and got me error, null at bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
```

`image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`

I need this code.

```
Matrix mat = new Matrix();
mat.postRotate(90);
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
bitmap_final = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mat, true);
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap_final);
```

Again, in emulator everything is fine, in phone not :/ Thanks for help and sorry for bad english

Comment: Maybe `imagePath` is valid on the emulator but not on the device, what is the path? Also are you saying that using the *same* method call but instead assigning to a variable fails?

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the problem. It was probably memory, I use method from documentation [setPic](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) and now is application without problem. But it's strange that it worked without problems in the emulator.